# Angular lazy loading for datatable makes sorting filtering paging not functional

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, primeng

Hello i implemented lazyloading for my datatable but the issue is now that my sorting and filtering and paging doesnt work. if i remove lazy loading then it works just fine

this is my html

```
 <p-table
      #dt
      [value]="lazy"
      [columns]="cols"
      [scrollable]="true"
      [tableStyle]="{ 'min-width': '50rem' }"
      scrollHeight="flex"
      [globalFilterFields]="['time','temperature','humidity','wind', 'pressure', 'direction', 'precipitation', 'rain', 'cloudcover','soilTemperature']"
      [rows]="10"
      [paginator]="true"
      [lazy]="true"
      (onLazyLoad)="loadData($event)"
      [loading]="loading"
    >
    <ng-template pTemplate="caption">
      <div *ngIf="filterSwitch" class="flex">
          <button pButton label="Clear"
          class="p-button-outlined"
          icon="pi pi-filter-slash"
          (click)="clearFilters(dt)">
        </button>
          <span >
              <i class="pi pi-search"></i>
              <input
              class="filter-input"
              pInputText
              type="text"
              (input)="dt.filterGlobal($event.target.value, 'contains')" />
          </span>
      </div>
  </ng-template>
      <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
        <tr class="icons">
          <th
          style="min-width:250px"
          [pSortableColumn]="col.field"
          *ngFor="let col of columns">
            <fa-icon [icon]="col.icon"></fa-icon>
            {{col.header}}
            <p-sortIcon [field]="col.field"></p-sortIcon>
            <p-columnFilter
            *ngIf="filterSwitch"
            [type]="col.type"
            display="menu"
            [field]="col.field">
          </p-columnFilter>
          </th>
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-weather let-columns="columns">
        <tr>
          <td *ngFor="let col of columns">{{ weather[col.field] + col.value }}</td>
        </tr>
      </ng-template>
    </p-table>
```

this is my ts

```
export class WeatherDataComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @ViewChild('dt') table: Table;
  showError: string;
  weatherData: WeatherDataItem[] = [];
  private componentDestroyed$: Subject<boolean> = new Subject();
  weatherDataLoading: boolean;
  icons: IconDefinition[] = [
    faClock,
    faTemperatureHigh,
    faPercent,
    faWind,
    faGem,
    faDirections,
    faWater,
    faCloud,
  ];
  cols: WeatherDataCol[];
  loading: boolean = false;
  lazy: any;

  constructor(
    private weatherService: WeatherService,
    public datePipe: DatePipe
  ) {
    this.cols = [
      new WeatherDataCol('time', 'Time', 'text', '', this.icons[0]),
      new WeatherDataCol(
        'temperature',
        'Temperature',
        'text',
        '°C',
        this.icons[1]
      ),
      new WeatherDataCol('humidity', 'Humidity', 'numeric', '%', this.icons[2]),
      new WeatherDataCol('wind', 'Wind Speed', 'text', ' km/h', this.icons[3]),
      new WeatherDataCol(
        'pressure',
        'Air Pressure',
        'text',
        ' hPa',
        this.icons[4]
      ),
      new WeatherDataCol(
        'direction',
        'Wind Direction',
        'numeric',
        '°',
        this.icons[5]
      ),
      new WeatherDataCol(
        'precipitation',
        'Precipitation',
        'numeric',
        'mm',
        this.icons[6]
      ),
      new WeatherDataCol('rain', 'Rain', 'numeric', 'mm', this.icons[6]),
      new WeatherDataCol(
        'cloudcover',
        'Cloudcover',
        'numeric',
        'mm',
        this.icons[7]
      ),
      new WeatherDataCol(
        'soilTemperature',
        'Soil Temperature',
        'text',
        '°C',
        this.icons[1]
      ),
    ];
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.weatherDataLoading = true;
    this.weatherService
      .getWeatherData()
      .pipe(
        finalize(() => (this.weatherDataLoading = false)),
        takeUntil(this.componentDestroyed$)
      )
      .subscribe({
        next: (historicalWeatherData) => {
          const temperatures = historicalWeatherData.hourly.temperature_2m;
          const times = historicalWeatherData.hourly.time.map((time) =>
            this.datePipe.transform(time, 'shortTime')
          );
          const humidities = historicalWeatherData.hourly.relativehumidity_2m;
          const windSpeeds = historicalWeatherData.hourly.windspeed_10m;
          const airPressures = historicalWeatherData.hourly.surface_pressure;
          const windDirections = historicalWeatherData.hourly.winddirection_10m;
          const precipitations = historicalWeatherData.hourly.precipitation;
          const rain = historicalWeatherData.hourly.rain;
          const cloudcover = historicalWeatherData.hourly.cloudcover;
          const soilTemperatures =
            historicalWeatherData.hourly.soil_temperature_0_to_7cm;

          temperatures.forEach((value, i) => {
            this.weatherData.push(
              new WeatherDataItem(
                value,
                times[i],
                humidities[i],
                windSpeeds[i],
                airPressures[i],
                windDirections[i],
                precipitations[i],
                rain[i],
                cloudcover[i],
                soilTemperatures[i]
              )
            );
          });
        },
        error: () =>
          (this.showError =
            'Something went wrong. Please try refreshing the page'),
      });
    this.loading = true;
  }

  loadData(event: LazyLoadEvent) {
   this.loading = true;
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (this.weatherData) {
        this.lazy = this.weatherData.slice(event.first, event.first + event.rows);
        this.loading = false;
        console.log(this.weatherData);
      }
    }, 1000);
  }
```

for lazy loading i added this function

```
loadData(event: LazyLoadEvent) {
this.loading = true;
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (this.weatherData) {
        this.lazy = this.weatherData.slice(event.first, event.first + event.rows);
        this.loading = false;
        console.log(this.weatherData);
      }
    }, 1000);
  }
```

it doesnt work and i cant think of anything else that might be wrong, any ideas please ?

Comment: Ok so there are multiple errors i think. p-table component takes a [value] and you set it to the variable "lazy". But you didn't initialized "lazy". In the constructor you set your columns, that's fine. In the ngOnInit you get your data from the backend, but you shouldn't do all the data manipulation here (what you do after the subscribe) instead do it in a service or so for more clarity. It's not an error but it's recommended.

Comment: So you get your data from the backend and then you assign the values to the variable binded to your table ("lazy"). Then you should encapsulate you backend call with a behaviourSubject, and when loadData() fires, the backend call is repeated but this time with different values of "take" and "skip". Take is the number of values the backend should send, and skip is the number of data your backend should skip, and so making pages.

Comment: So there's backend work to do here. I assume you wanted to load all the data in "weatherData" and then fill up "lazy" with some data to makes pages. But it's a bad approach because the advantages of lazyness is lost here (since you load all of the data). Also in the ngOnInit, the "this.loading = true;" is weird because you juste loaded all the data so the loading should be finished.